# SpringBoot connection to Redis : Does not appear to be caching data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

I am using SpringBoot to connect to Redis. I have Web dependency on SpringBoot and  my intention is to write Product information to a runtime datastructure i.e., a Map. I want to test the Cache annotations that Spring provides to understand the usage.

Here is the POM.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.fireacademy</groupId>
    <artifactId>redisconnectivity</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>redisconnectivity</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot &amp; Redis connectivity</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is the Spring Application class

```
package io.fireacademy.redisconnectivity;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class RedisconnectivityApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RedisconnectivityApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is my main controller class

```
package io.fireacademy.redisconnectivity.controllers;

import io.fireacademy.redisconnectivity.model.Product;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CacheEvict;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/products")
public class WebAppController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebAppController.class);

    // This will serve as the database
    private Map<String, Product> m_productDatabase = new HashMap<String, Product>();

    @Cacheable(value="my-product-cache", key="#productId")
    private Product getProductFromCacheOrDB(String productId)
    {
        logger.info("Loading the Product " + productId + " from the cache!.");
        return m_productDatabase.get(productId);
    }

    @CacheEvict(value="my-product-cache", key="#productId")
    private Product deleteFromCache(String productId)
    {
        logger.info("Remove the Product " + productId + " from the cache!.");
        return m_productDatabase.get(productId);
    }

    @GetMapping(path="/")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> getProducts()
    {
        Collection<Product> allProducts = m_productDatabase.values();

        List<Product> allProductsAsList = allProducts.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());

        return new ResponseEntity<List<Product>>(allProductsAsList, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(path="/{productId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Product> getProducts(@PathVariable String productId)
    {
        // Either from the Cache or from the DB.
        Product product = getProductFromCacheOrDB(productId);

        return new ResponseEntity<Product>(product, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping(consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<Product> createProduct(@RequestBody Product product)
    {
        m_productDatabase.put(product.getId(), product);

        return new ResponseEntity<Product>(product, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @PutMapping(path="/{productId}",
                consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
                produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<Product> updateProduct(@PathVariable String productId, @RequestBody Product product)
    {
        m_productDatabase.put(productId, product);
        return new ResponseEntity<Product>(product, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(path="/{productId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Product> deleteProduct(@PathVariable String productId)
    {
        Product deletedProduct = getProductFromCacheOrDB(productId);
        deleteFromCache(productId);

        return new ResponseEntity<Product>(deletedProduct, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Here is my RedisConfig class

```
package io.fireacademy.redisconnectivity.configurations;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisStandaloneConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.redis.repository.configuration.EnableRedisRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer;

@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories
public class RedisConfig {

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration configuration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        configuration.setHostName("localhost");
        configuration.setPort(6379);
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(configuration);
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> template() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashKeySerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
        template.setValueSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
        template.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
        template.afterPropertiesSet();
        return template;
    }
}
```

My application.properties looks as below:

```
# Redis Config
spring.cache.type=redis
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.port=6379
```

And I am running Redis as a docker container using this:

```
docker run -d -p 6379:6379 --name my-redis redis
```

When I inspect the docker container's logs, I see nothing happening.

```
D:\Development\springboot\learn_redis>docker logs -f c376f1be9be35281b900c2943fbf8ea37e1563157efb57d46ca1c74fc880bc5c
1:C 04 Jun 2022 17:49:51.854 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
1:C 04 Jun 2022 17:49:51.854 # Redis version=7.0.0, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
1:C 04 Jun 2022 17:49:51.854 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
1:M 04 Jun 2022 17:49:51.854 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
1:M 04 Jun 2022 17:49:51.858 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
1:M 04 Jun 2022 17:49:51.858 # Server initialized
1:M 04 Jun 2022 17:49:51.858 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
1:M 04 Jun 2022 17:49:51.858 * The AOF directory appendonlydir doesn't exist
1:M 04 Jun 2022 17:49:51.858 * Ready to accept connections
```

My understanding was that the Cache annotations would make the data be stored onto the Redis cache. For instance, the getProductFromCacheOrDB, should store the Product object onto the cache with the input productId as the key because of the @Cacheable annotation and a subsequent call to get this specific Product using the GET productId should not invoke the method again. But this is not happening.

Please show some pointers on what I could have missed...

Thanks,
Pavan.

Edits:

1. I do not see anything on Redis getting created. I enabled monitoring on Redis via the redis-cli, but see nothing.
2. I tried removing the RedisConfig class and see no change.

Comment: Did you specify @EnableCaching?

Comment: @voidvoid Yes, I did. I updated the question with that relevant snippet.

Comment: Can you add your build.gradle or maven file?

Comment: @voidvoid I have added it now. Please check.

Comment: I think you need to add spring-boot-starter-cache to take advatange of auto configuration

Comment: Added this dependency and see no change. Im reading through the documentation to cross check if I have ticked all the checks.

Comment: One more pointer would be to connect to redis with redis-cli and check if you have any key-values added using: "keys *", to diagnose if it's added to redis at all.

Answer (score 1):

Just created a simple working example at https://github.com/bsbodden/basic-caching-spring-data-redis

What you need:

1. POM dependencies:

   ```xml
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. In the app class or configurer `@EnableCaching`:

   ```java
   @SpringBootApplication
   @EnableCaching
   public class DemoApplication {
   ```
3. In the app class `RedisCacheManager` bean:

   ```java
   @Bean
   public RedisCacheManager cacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
     RedisCacheConfiguration config = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig() //
         .prefixCacheNameWith(this.getClass().getPackageName() + ".") //
         .entryTtl(Duration.ofHours(1)) //
         .disableCachingNullValues();

     return RedisCacheManager.builder(connectionFactory) //
         .cacheDefaults(config) //
         .build();
   }
   ```
4. `@Cacheable` in your controller:

   ```java
   @GetMapping("/{id}")
   @Cacheable("some-cache")
   public SomeModel get(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
     return repo.findById(id).orElse(SomeModel.of("nope"));
   }
   ```